# Extract text from PDF with a right to left language

Tags: windows, pdf, export, right-to-left

I'm trying to extract text from a PDF with right to left language, and the text is get is mirrored. This happens in Nitro Reader 2 and Adobe Reader.

How can I do it so that the text extracted will be in the right order?

Comment: What program are you using to extract the text?

Comment: Nitro Reader 2 and Adobe Reader

Comment: And where are you extracting it to?

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Windows, you can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to convert from RTF to LTF.

This option can be found under: **View** > `Text Direction LTR`.

[image: left to right]

You may also need to change the **encoding** as well.

### Update:

This only changes the view of the text, not the format of the text itself.